# Handling Flags Against Yourself

Tags: feature-request, moderation, flagging

When someone flags a post, can the author of that post handle the flag himself?

(I'm hoping the answer is no!)

---

Based on some research, it seems mods *can* in fact dismiss flags against their own posts. As such, I have retagged this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) so that this can be changed. I believe that mods are naturally biased towards their own posts and therefore not in a position to accurately judge complaints against them. These flags should be left for other mods to handle.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136596/166155

Comment: (FWIW I don't actually support this post anymore, but that's not basis for deleting it.)

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This answer was to the earlier version of this question.*

---

Not unless the user is a moderator. Your list of moderators is here:

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: I think that was the presumption. Are you saying that if I (theoretically) flagged your post, you could dismiss it?

Comment: @HodofHod Yes that was my intention.

Comment: @HodofHod Now that you're a mod we can try this out! (I really want to flag this post here for Jeff to see, but....)

Comment: @DoubleAA It works!